# Access for PHP Class Method

Tags: php, oop, methods

I am new to Object Oriented PHP and have a question about where to implement access restrictions.

I have some methods that can be used by anyone but some that make a database update and should only be accessed by a certain user level.

Is the Class Method an appropriate place to add that logic or should it be kept clean and put that logic around where the method call is made.

```
$product = new Product($id);
$product->setCategory($category);

public function setCategory($category)
{
    if(get_access(5)) {
        Item::where('id', $this->id)->update(['category' => $category]);
        $this->category = $category;
    }
}
```

OR

```
$product = new Product($id);
if(get_access(5)) {
    $product->setCategory($category);
}

public function setCategory($category)
{
        Item::where('id', $this->id)->update(['category' => $category]);
        $this->category = $category;
}
```

OR

Some other way I haven't thought of.

Comment: Are you using a User class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally permissions are handled by another layer and are not strictly coupled with specific classes themselves.

Since this topic would be too much for a single answer, I recommend reading articles in common PHP frameworks on how to handle authorization, e.g. [Zend](https://framework.zend.com/blog/2017-05-04-authorization-middleware.html), [Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authorization.html), [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization) or others.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using Laravel framework which have an authentication middleware https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication or you can see other middleware at https://heera.it/laravel-5-1-x-acl-middleware. In case you use other frameworks, I think they support this problem. If you implement access restrictions like above, it'll be hard for you or other developers when they want to change somethings later and debug.